# Dynamically load div content after DOM is ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Sirs, I am quite sure the solution of my task is invented a long time ago, and I don't want accidentally to reinvent the wheel. I use Classic ASP.NET and jQuery. So, the task is:

1. Browser requests a page, for instance, `CreateOrder.aspx`.
2. ASP.NET returns HTML with no actual content and empty `div`s where I want to show my content.
3. Browser makes additional requests, retrieves all the data and puts it into `div`s.

Is there any out-of-the-box technology in ASP.NET to achieve this transparently? Maybe some sort of `UpdatePanel`? Again, I do not want to load anything from database in `Page_Load`.

Answer (score 0):

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` (.NET) will register a script block at the end of the document.  This isn't exactly on DOM ready but was a common practice in the earlier days of the web.

If using jQuery you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Your code */
});
```

Comment: I know about `ready`, but what I should do there? Manually call some ASHX handlers, return chunks of HTML code, and manually put it in `div`s? Where is `out-of-the-box` here?

Comment: You should be able to do that with an UpdatePanel and/or jQuery.  You just need to select an event to trigger the asynchronous call.  Then take the returned markup and inject it into the content div.  It's your choice how you want to go about handling this.  jQuery is a more light weight option since you don't have the viewstate etc. in the partial post back that .NET uses.